# Given a triangular arrangement of numbers ($2018$ at top, $2017$ and $2016$ in next row, etc), find the last number in the $50$th row

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

Is the formula $\frac12n(n-1) - k$ for the $k$th element in the $n$th row? It would be the sum of the differences minus the element you want.

---

And if I wanted to find the sum of the numbers in the $60$th row, would I use the formula mentioned above to find the last number of the $59$th row and then do $\frac12 n(n+1)$ to find the sum of all those numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence is decreasing, hence your formula can't be right.

It should have been $$2019 - \frac{n(n-1)}{2}-k$$

If you want to sum the $n$-th row, just compute

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(2019 - \frac{n(n-1)}{2}-k\right)$$ which is an arithmetic sum.

Comment: Thank you! how can I compute the arithmetic sum? I know that in general it is $\frac{n}{2} (a_1+a_n)$ but that doesn't look like the sum you have above.

Comment: You can find the first element of the row and the last element of the row isn't it?

Comment: oh, duh! sorry that was really dumb of me. so the first element would be 2018, the last element would be 2019 - 60*59/2 - 59 = 190. so it would be 60/2 *2018+190, right?

Comment: If you at the $n$-th row where $n>1$, the first element is not $2018$. you should set $k$ to be $1$.

Comment: why is the first element not 2018? Are you saying to start from the reverse? and make  the first element 190 and the last element 2018? i'm confused

Comment: Suppose you want to sum up the second row, what is the first number?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I must have phrased the question incorrectly. What I meant was how can I sum up all the numbers from the first row all the way to the 60th. Not just sum up the 60th row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84892/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-user8290579).